# IdentityServer: server-to-server authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, webapi

Just a question:
Since I'm new to Identity server and I'm trying to understand what can I do (and of course what I cannot), there's a way I can authenticate users with a server-to-server approach?

That's my case: I have a website running on an Authentication API. This auth API needs to connect to IdentityServer (on another server) and return if this user is authenticated.

What I want to reach is to authenticate the user without prompting another login screen.
Someone can explain how can I reach that (and of course IF I can reach that)?

Thanks.

Dario.

Comment: Are you looking for the On-Behalf-Of flow?

Comment: I basically need to secure authentication with a central auth server. In this way many website can be accessed through the same account, so the login will be unique and even the user profile.